# Meaning of "shorthand letters" in a Python for loop?

Tags: python

In many examples I have seen what I simply call shorthand operators. Most often they come up in loops and list related functions. I have not found a resource that explains what they are, or their meanings. What do these letters represent in Python?

```
for x in list:
for i in range(10):
for c in "hello, world":
```

I'm talking about the single letters after the `for`: `x`, `i`, `c`, and others.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Loops#For_Loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not operators, those are iteration variables. The point of a loop is to sequentially bind that variable to a value take from the iterable (in your example called `list`).

They can have any name whatsoever without affecting programme semantics (just due to the name). Note that they are a normal variable of the scope they are introduced in, so will be affected by `global` declarations, and live after the loop has been exited.

Comment: "They can have any name whatsoever without affecting programme semantics (just due to the name)." thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

While the name used for the iteration variable in a `for` loop is entirely up to you, as Marcin notes, I'll add that single-letter names are often used and certain ones have developed a convention around them. While usually using brief names is frowned upon since they can be cryptic, the body of a loop is typically short enough that you won't forget their meaning, and they will be frequently referred to within the loop, so you save some typing.

Examples might include `i`, `j`, and `k` for indices, `x` as a general placeholder (also `x`, `y`, and `z` for Cartesian coordinates), `t` for time or tuple (e.g. when iterating over a list of tuples; you might also see `d` when iterating a list of dicts, `o` for a list of objects), `c` for character and `w` for word (e.g. when iterating through a string), or `k` and `v` for key and value when iterating through a dictionary's items.

You may also see `_` (a single underscore) for an iteration variable that's not used, for example in a list comprehension like `[[] for _ in range(5)]`, which creates five new lists that are not the same object. You need an iteration variable to receive the values from `range()` but the point of the loop is to execute it five times, not to do anything with those values.